# async function in flask allows telegram-bot to get only one file properties

Tags: python, flask, async-await, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I need telegram-bot to open files from clients. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import asyncio
import telegram

app = Flask(__name__)
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)

# Recieve files from Telegram
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    data = request.get_json()
    file_id = data['message']['document']['file_id']
    
    async def get_path (file_id):
        global file_info
        file_info = await bot.get_file (file_id)
        return file_info

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    logging.info(f"loop={loop}")
    asyncio.run (get_path(file_id))
    logging.info (f"file_path={file_info.file_path}") 

# launch Flask
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:
For 1-st file downloaded to bot:

```
INFO 83: loop=<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
INFO 113: file_path=https://api.telegram.org/file/bot557***:***VF0FrPEGq9CnchBHQ4IMzR4oAY/documents/file_28.xlsx
```

from the 2-nd and more files expected the same resultes as from 1-st file,
but output is:

```
Exception on / [POST]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 274, in _request_wrapper
     code, payload = await self.do_request(
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/request/_httpxrequest.py", line 199, in do_request
     res = await self._client.request(
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1533, in request
     return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1620, in send
     response = await self._send_handling_auth(
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1648, in _send_handling_auth
     response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1685, in _send_handling_redirects
     response = await self._send_single_request(request)
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1722, in _send_single_request
     response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 353, in handle_async_request
     resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 220, in handle_async_request
     await self._close_expired_connections()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 188, in _close_expired_connections
     await connection.aclose()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 159, in aclose
     await self._connection.aclose()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 313, in aclose
     await self._network_stream.aclose()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/backends/asyncio.py", line 54, in aclose
     await self._stream.aclose()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 192, in aclose
     await self.transport_stream.aclose()
File "/home/proj/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1323, in aclose
     self._transport.close()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 706, in close
     self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 753, in call_soon
     self._check_closed()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
     raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

the error appears from this line (from second time looping):

```
file_info = await bot.get_file (file_id)
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Comment: 0stone0, thanks. I edited question and token.

Comment: Please have a look at [this page](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/examples.html#examples-customwebhookbot) where `python-telegram-bot` provides examples on how to run PTB alongside flask

Comment: CallMeStag, thank you. The example code you linked to makes a lot of things, but does not support downloading files from users to the bot